# Can't access WordPress site in subfolder possibly because of .htaccess redirect from root installation?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I currently have one Wordpress installation in the root directory.

I have now uploaded an entirely different (and second) Wordpress installation in /beta/ - connected to a second and separate database.

**The issue:**
When requesting the second installation: `domain.com/beta/` it simply shows to a "404 not found page" within the theme of the first installation.

So seems that I cannot access the second installation because some redirecting from the first installation.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**The .htaccess from the first (root) `domain.com` installation looks as so:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**The .htaccess from the second `domain.com/beta/` installation looks as so:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the line

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

or change to

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(beta|wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

in the root .htaccess file.